# Infinite file output

Tags: c

```
void echoFileA(const char* iPath,const char* oPath)
{
    FILE* iFile;
    FILE* oFile;

    iFile = fopen(iPath,"rb");
    oFile = fopen(oPath,"wb");

    while(iFile)    
        fputc(fgetc(iFile),oFile);

    fclose(iFile);
    fclose(oFile);
}
```

The procedure was written purely for fun, I know that there are covenient ,  premade functions for copying files in the every OS API libriaries. Back to the topic- why the loop condition is always true, even if the EOF was reached a long time ago?
I've checked that I've passed the correct parameters to this function in the testing program.

Comment: It's not ignored.  `iFile` doesn't reach a case in which it becomes 0.

Comment: What EVIDENCE do you have that its being ignored?  What did you expect to happen, and what actually happened?

Comment: Sorry about that ambiguity , question corrected and precised  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The body of your loop ...

```
   fputc(fgetc(iFile),oFile);
```

... does nothing to change the condition of the loop, so it will run forever.

Instead try something like ...

```
int c;
while((c = fgetc(iFile)) != EOF) 
   fputc(c, oFile);
```

The loop will end once you hit the end of the input file.

Comment: To be more concise try ...   while(fputc(fgetc(iFile),oFile) != EOF);

Answer (score 3):

The condition is not being ignored. iFile is a pointer and since this pointer is never NULL (or rather 0) the while condition is always true.

Try something like:

```
while(!feof(iFile))    
        fputc(fgetc(iFile),oFile);
```

To make the while loop continue until the end of the file has been reached.

Comment: This results in an infinite loop if the input file gets in an error condition (`feof` remains false but no reads are performed).

Answer (score 2):

`iFile` is just a pointer to the file. It does not change anymore after you call `fopen`. As a condition in the loop you need to use, for instance, the return value from `fgetc`, since that will tell you whether you have reached the end of the file.